# Is it possible to use MemoryRouter nested in BrowserRouter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been searching, and trying for a while now, however I couldn't find an answer if it is possible to use MemoryRouter for only specific routes while I use BrowserRouter in general. I wan t to navigate to a certain component but not change the url, tried it like so, but it changes the url but not rendering the component, the complete opposite what I wish.

```
     <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
            <Route path="/" component={MainPage} />
            <MemoryRouter>
              <Route
                path='/somecomponent'
                component={SomeComponent}
              />
            </MemoryRouter>
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Routes inside the MemoryRouter are relative to the MemoryRouter, not to your current location as displayed in the URL bar.

As far as it's concerned, the current route is `"/"`, and it will only render components at `<Route path="/">`. If you were to add

```
<Route path="/">
    <Redirect to="/somecomponent" />
</Route>
```

directly under `MemoryRouter` it should go to the path you're looking for, and render as intended.